# Blazor - says BuildRenderTree is already defined

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to add the method `protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder b)` to one of my classes. I was first able to. But all of a sudden, in every razor file I try, adding it gives me the following error:

```
Error   CS0111  Type 'LoginOrRegister' already defines a member called 'BuildRenderTree' with the same parameter types  LouisHowe.web   C:\Git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Pages\User\LoginOrRegister.razor.cs  43  Active
```

I finally in desperation undid all changes (as it was initially accepting it), ran clean solution, exited and restarted Visual Studio. Still get the error.

I then created a new .razor file and tried to add `BuildRenderTree` to that file - same error.

And a text search of the solution for "BuildRenderTree" finds only 1 place - where I'm trying to add it.

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: check the SDK version `dotnet --version` matches the target framework declared in your csproj and the versions on any extension nugets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BuildRenderTree` is defined in `ComponentBase` as follows:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Renders the component to the supplied <see cref="RenderTreeBuilder"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">A <see cref="RenderTreeBuilder"/> that will receive the render output.</param>
    protected virtual void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        // Developers can either override this method in derived classes, or can use Razor
        // syntax to define a derived class and have the compiler generate the method.

        // Other code within this class should *not* invoke BuildRenderTree directly,
        // but instead should invoke the _renderFragment field.
    }
```

So you can override `BuildRenderTree` in a class you define that inherits from `ComponentBase`.

I'm being very precise here in defining `class`.  You can't override it in a Razor file.  Not now, and not in the past.

Why?

The Razor compiler takes all the markup in the Razor file [not within a code section] and compiles it into `RenderTreeBuilder` instructions in a method called `BuildRenderTree`.  So if you add such a method to the code section of a Razor file, or to a code behind file, you will be defining two methods with the same signature.  And the main compiler doesn't like that!

So whatever you've changed, it isn't what you think you've changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so [according to this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37797) BuildRenderTree is not to be overridden.

I'm guessing it's virtual for the case where a class is just .cs with no .razor component.

[Which should enable code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274355/blazor-pages-how-to-use-buildrendertree-to-add-dynamic-content) - although I can't get that to work for me (it does not add the additional elements).

Comment: There is nothing new about this and it's not about virtual/override.  The sole purpose of a .razor file is to generate a BuildRenderTree() and you can only have one.