# How can I add a component to the end of all super class razor files?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

On all of my page razor files I want to add the following to the bottom:

```
<DxLoadingPanel Visible="@Visible"
                PositionTarget="body"
                IsContentBlocked="true"
                ApplyBackgroundShading="true" />
```

All of my pages inherit from a base class like this:

```
@page "/User/Search"
@inherits ExPageBase

public partial class Search : ExPageBase
```

`ExPageBase` is a .cs file only, no .razor file. [I tried the example here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274355/blazor-pages-how-to-use-buildrendertree-to-add-dynamic-content)

```
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder b)
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(b);
        b.OpenElement(0, "div");
        b.AddMarkupContent(1, TheContent());
        b.CloseElement();
    }
```

That shows the razor file content, but did not show the added elements. I'm guessing the issue I'm facing is this is a base class with the super class razor file then overriding this.

I'm open to any approach to accomplish this. But I'd like to not have to drop this component in every page. I looked at putting it in `MainLayout` but the inner page razor file has no easy way to set `MainLayout.Visible` parameter.

Comment: Not easy with `ComponentBase` because it's not designed that way.  Net8 and 
`SectionOutlet`/`SectionContent` will offer some options.  My solution is not to use `ComponentBase` as described here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5364401/Building-Blazor-Base-Components

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do.  However, there are at least 2 good ways to communicate state change with the layout page: 1) cascade the layout page using the "this" keyword, pick it up as a cascaded parameter in any child (or grandchild) you want, and directly change whatever you want (say, a boolean flag in the layout page); 2) Use a service to hold state and communicate changes through an event.